Pyspark column ambiguous depending on the order of the join
With this example:
data = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'Casper', 'age': 2}, {'name': 'Agatha', 'age': 3}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df_1 = df.select("name", df["age"].alias("q"))

1.- If I do the join in the following way there is no problem:
df.join(df_1, "name").select("name", df.age).show()

2.- But if I do exactly the same join in this way it raises an error saying that column "age" is ambiguous:
df_1.join(df, "name").select("name", df.age).show()

AnalysisException: Column age#0L are ambiguous. It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. `df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`. You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.

In both cases the join is the same and it only has one column named "age".
df.join(df_1, "name").show()

+------+---+---+
|  name|age|  q|
+------+---+---+
|Agatha|  3|  3|
| Alice|  1|  1|
|Casper|  2|  2|
+------+---+---+

Why the select in the second case throws an error of column ambiguous if there is only one column named "age"?
And why it only throws the error in the second case?

I believe this is occurring because df_1 is essentially the same as df, so you are joining the same DataFrame with itself, and Pyspark is pulling age#0L from the same location in memory, even when you have aliased it. We can check the memory locations using .explain:
df.explain()
df_1.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[age#0L,name#1]

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [name#1, age#0L AS q#4L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[age#0L,name#1]

If you create an entirely new DataFrame df_2, then it's stored in a different location in memory.
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df_2.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[age#46L,name#47]

And you can join df to df_2 in either order.

Bad catalyst afaics.

This is the usual gotcha with self joins (or joins between Dataframes that have columns with same name). You've picked more or less the only syntax  (df.age) that will fail for your case.
The error message very clearly tells you what to do.

...Please alias the Datasets with different names via Dataset.as before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id"). You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.

Reason why it does not work is due to the way columns are resolved when you specify them using F.col('col_name') vs 'col_name' vs df.col_name vs '<alias>.col_name'.
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'Casper', 'age': 2}, {'name': 'Agatha', 'age': 3}])
df_1 = df.select("name", df["age"].alias("q"))

>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>>
>>> df_1.join(df, "name").select("name", "age").show()
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|Agatha|  3|
| Alice|  1|
|Casper|  2|
+------+---+
>>>
>>> df_1.join(df, "name").select("name", F.col("age")).show()
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|Agatha|  3|
| Alice|  1|
|Casper|  2|
+------+---+
>>>
>>> df_1.join(df.alias('a'), "name").select("name", "a.age").show()
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|Agatha|  3|
| Alice|  1|
|Casper|  2|
+------+---+


Pick one way and stick with it. Spark and I recommend using aliases.

Some reading:

Pyspark: Reference is ambiguous when joining dataframes on same column
Removing duplicate columns after a DF join in Spark

